# Grails 1.3.4 plugin downloading issues

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am running application on `grails 1.3.4` but I am getting this error while running applicaton.

```
Base Directory: /projects/upwork/jhon/jbilling-community-3.1.0_2
WARNING: Configurational method [inherits] in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy doesn't exist. Ignoring..
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 804ms.
Running script /apps/grails-1.3.4/scripts/RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
Plugin [release-2.2.1] not installed. ...
Plugin [release-1.0.0] not installed. ...
Plugin [rest-client-builder-1.0.3] not installed. ...
Resolving new plugins. Please wait... ...
Installing zip /Users/bilalshah/.ivy2/cache/org.grails.plugins/release/zips/release-2.2.1.zip... ...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/bilalshah/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling-community-3.1.0_2/plugins/release-2.2.1
    [unzip] Expanding: /Users/bilalshah/.ivy2/cache/org.grails.plugins/release/zips/release-2.2.1.zip into /Users/bilalshah/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling-community-3.1.0_2/plugins/release-2.2.1
Installed plugin release-2.2.1 to location /Users/bilalshah/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling-community-3.1.0_2/plugins/release-2.2.1. ...
Plugin release-2.2.1 requires version [2.0 > *] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet. Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails.
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/bilalshah/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling-community-3.1.0_2/plugins/release-2.2.1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I haven't mentioned any plugin named above in my `application.properties` file. Here it is:

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Wed Jun 15 19:34:11 PKT 2016
app.grails.version=1.3.4
app.name=jbilling
app.servlet.version=2.4
app.version=community-3.1.0
plugins.cookie=0.2
plugins.cxf=0.5.1
plugins.hibernate=1.3.4
plugins.include=0.3
plugins.jquery=1.11.1
plugins.jquery-ui=1.8.7
plugins.log4j-xml=0.2
plugins.remote-pagination=0.2.4
plugins.remoting=1.1
plugins.spring-security-core=1.0.1
plugins.tomcat=1.3.4
plugins.webflow=1.3.8
```

Can anyone let me know why it is happening and its solution.

Comment: Did you try to grep through directory of your project looking for strings such as "rest-client-builder-1.0.3" or "rest-client-builder" and check from where are they called?

Comment: no. How can I do that?